# Могу ли я передать значение сразу нескольким объектам?

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Мне нужно сделать остановку объектов при касании.
При касание значение int = -1.Мне нужно передать это значение сразу нескольким объектам с одним скриптом.
Передаю значение строками.
`GameObject.Find("First").GetComponent<Move>().Audit = -1;` 
`GameObject.Find("Second").GetComponent<Move>().Audit = -1;`
Нужно что бы это делалось одной строкой (В конце проекта будет много игровых объектов и передавать каждому не вариант).

Comment: Если у вас будет "много" таких объектов, то у вас потенциально может упасть фпс.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте один из этих способов для поиска объектов, они возвращают коллекцию

```
// ищет в сцене объект по типу
foreach (var move in FindObjectsOfType<Move> ()) {
    move.Audit = -1;
}

// ищет компонент ниже по иерархии от текущего объекта
foreach (var move in GetComponentsInChildren<Move> ()) {
    move.Audit = -1;
}
```

Comment: и да, это медленно