# Передача значения переменной другим объектам

Tags: c#, unity3d

Уже [задавал вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/972235/213987) но остались некоторые нюансы.
Суть заключается в том что у меня есть некое значение q и мне нужно при прикосновении уменьшать его на единицу (q=-1).
При прикосновении оно уменьшается только в одном скрипте , а нужно что бы оно искало объекты с скриптом и уменьшало q .
Передаю я значение строками(Если объекта нету на сцене тогда код работает неправильно):

```
GameObject.Find("First").GetComponent<Move>().Audit = -1;  
GameObject.Find("Second").GetComponent<Move>().Audit = -1;
```

В конце проекта будет много игровых объектов и передавать каждому не вариант.

Один из вариантов(Но сказали что он медленный.Может есть другие способы или эти единственные наилучшие?)
Используйте один из этих способов для поиска объектов, они возвращают коллекцию

```
// ищет в сцене объект по типу
foreach (var move in FindObjectsOfType<Move> ()) {
    move.Audit = -1;
}

// ищет компонент ниже по иерархии от текущего объекта
foreach (var move in GetComponentsInChildren<Move> ()) {
    move.Audit = -1;
}
```

Comment: как именно не правильно работает `find`?

Comment: Если вы о первых двух строках то find работает хорошо , но если же объекта нету на сцене то код просто дальше на работает. Поэтому и нужно сделать автоматический поиск.

Comment: ну да....если объекта нет на сцене или он не активен, то `find` вернет `null`...остается всего-то сделать проверку на него

Comment: Я не могу вручную писать код на поиск 40-80 объектов да и код будет очень большой.

Comment: если в цикле не получается осуществить поиск, то придется....там есть еще поик по тегам (возможно он вам больше подойдет)

Comment: Если вы наотрез отказываетесь при инстанциировании сохранять ссылки, то поиск через `FindObjectsOfType<Move>` - единственное решение. Более того, множество объектов с одинаковым `MonoBehaviour` скриптом - медленная реализация.

Comment: Поиск в цикле получается осуществить , но практично ли это (по времени и затратам) . Вот в чем вопрос.

Comment: Если вы готовы потратить время на изучении новой и комплексной технологии, то новая ECS от Unity - это именно то, что вам нужно в данной ситуации.

Comment: Вам нужно осуществить этот поиск ровно 1 раз за сцену, просто сохраняйте все ссылки в список/массив и уже потом с ним работайте.

Comment: Поиск как раз и будет происходить ровно один раз

Comment: А изучение ECS от Unity не очень хороший вариант для меня (владею минимальными знаниями для работы с юнити )

Comment: Возможно,потом вернусь к этому.

Comment: Используйте, пожалуйста, `@`, иначе я не увижу оповещения. Если вы используете этот поиск 1 раз - делайте это "во время загрузки", вот и все.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Попытаюсь реализовать.Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Есть такие варианты. Если у вас разные объекты но у ниx тот же самый скрипт соберите все эти элементы в массив и меняйте значение циклом. Допустим у вас массив под названием ObjectsArray, объекты - SampleObject а скрипт - SampleScript

```
for(int i = 0; i < ObjectsArray.lenght; i++)
{
    SampleScript sampleScript = SampleObject[i].GetComponent<SampleScript>();
    sampleScript.q--;
}
```

А чтобы вам было легче вы можете не искать иx на сцене а при создании объекта сразу добавить его в массив (с помощью Push) ведь вы не создавайте 40-80 объектов ручным образом.
Push - https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Array.Push.html
Instantiate - https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html

```
GameObject SampleObject = Instantiate(ObjectPrefab, ObjectsParent /*родитель объектов*/)
ObjectsArray.Push(SampleObject);
```

А если у вас разные скрипты делайте один из ниx главным а остальные меняйте вот так с помощью GetComponent так же как сверху.
GetComponent - https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html

По поводу скорости не скажу что это прям свет но не так уж медленно работает.